# Mask part of a model with another one in Libgdx

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx

There is a need to mask or crop part of a 3D model in Libgdx by another model. Assuming the attached images, there are two boxes which I need to crop green box with red one on-the-fly (if the camera view changes the specific part should be cropped as well) and the result should be like the other image.Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

[image: two models]

[image: cropped model]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question and to provide what you already tried. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Looking at your images it should work just fine if you change the color of the red box to black.

Comment: Thanks Xoppa but I've already ask how to crop part of a model with another one. Changing red box to black is a good idea but my question is not that simple! I am going to make the background color transparent for an augmented reality app; so red box should be transparent too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied the depth buffer to mask my 3D model and it works fine. Here is my snippet code.

```
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
Gdx.gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_LESS);
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
Gdx.gl.glDepthMask(true);
Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, false);

//the mask model
modelBatch.begin(cam);
modelBatch.render(redBox);
modelBatch.end();

// the model which is masked
modelBatch.begin(cam);
Gdx.gl.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
Gdx.gl.glDepthFunc(GL20.GL_EQUAL);
modelBatch.render(greenBox);
modelBatch.end();
```

And special thanks to [Matt DesLauriers](https://gist.github.com/mattdesl/6076849).

Comment: I'm looking to mask out a piece from a wall model and then place a window or door model. The problem im having is the mask model is removing everything behind it and I cannot seem to redraw it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the libgdx but using the Stencil buffer (if supported) could be a help. It's additional buffer that allows you to mark specific pixels with an integer value, then during the main rendering you can setup some stencil tests to decide which pixels should be discarded.

In short:

- Clean Stencil buffer to 0
- Draw red object only in stencil buffer, with value e.g. 1
- Set stencil test to 'is zero'
- Draw green object normally

This way you draw green box as usual, but ignore pixels for which stencil != 0, which means all occluded by a red box.

Comment: Thanks kolenda! I checked the library but it seems Stencil buffer and Depth buffer can be used for 2D space.